# How to apply scaleModifier to Animated Sprite when it is touched (AndEngine)

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I want to apply scaleModifier on a Sprite when it is touched. I apply the scaleModifier like below:

```
mMySprite.registerEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(2f, 1f, 0.5f));
```

There is also a Dynamic body attached to this. I read that the body will not be changed but atleast the sprite should be scaled. But nothing happens. Can any one tell me how can I do this and whats missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
     ....
     (Some AnimatedSprite object).registerEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(2, 1, 0.5f));
     ....
}
```

And it works fine. Make sure that if you use `IOnSceneTouchListener` you also register it:

```
scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(...);
```

Or, if you decided to override `onAreaTouch` method, make sure you register your animated sprite as a touch area:

```
scene.registerTouchArea(yourAnimatedSprite);
```

Comment: Well I noticed another problem, I was having a separate class for my AnimatedSprite with proper constructor etc. When I removed that class and tried it worked. I don't know what was the problem in having separate class.

Comment: If you overrided `onAreaTouched` and registered your new class instance with the `Scene.registerTouchArea` method, it should work.